# Prove U(n) as an External Direct Product.

Tags: group-theory

Notation: If k is a divisor of n, $$U_{k}(n) = { \{x \in U(n) | x\bmod  k =1}\}$$

and $U(n)$, which is the set of all positive integers  relatively prime to $n$ that are greater than or equal to one or less than or equal to $n−1$.

So I have proved the first part of this theorem which states

> Suppose $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime. Then prove that $U(st)$ is isomorphic to the external direct product of $U(s)$ and $U(t)$. Moreover, prove that $U_{s} (st) $ is isomorphic to $U(t)$.

So I have proved this part : $U(st) \cong U(s) \oplus  U(t)$ by showing bijection and homomorphism. Here, I considered the mapping from $U(st)$ to $U(s) \oplus U(t)$ defined as $x \mapsto (x \bmod s, x \bmod t)$.

Now comes the part where I have to prove, $U_{s} (st)$ is isomorphic to $U(t)$. I am not able to prove this. I am stuck in the one-one and onto part.

In one-one, I am confused if I consider the mapping from $x \mapsto x \bmod t$, then by just showing $x_1 \bmod t= x_2 \bmod t$ will be enough?

And I don't know how to proceed with the onto part.

Comment: You don't tell us what "this" is. You don't tell us what your notation means. And you don't tell us why you are stuck.

Comment: Please define in particular $U_s(...)$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh I am very sorry, it is a theorem in my textbook. Let me rewrite my question properly. You don't have to be this rude.

Comment: I was not rude. You've been on the site for nine months. Your post shows a complete lack of interest in abiding by the standards of the site. That might be considered rude.

Comment: Thank you; but you still haven't told us what $U(s)$ means (I can guess, but I shouldn't have to), or what $U_s(st)$ means (again, I can guess, but I shouldn't have to).

Comment: I hope I have written everything now. :)

Comment: Thank you; please look at the edits I made so that you can properly format your post next time. [Here is a Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742), and here is the FAQ on [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/742) so it only takes one try the next time.

Comment: In fact your issue can be connected to the study of [Euler totient function $\varphi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)